# What does ?<id> do in nginx.conf's location?

Tags: postgresql, nginx, openresty

Does ? denote that it will be accessible to ngx_postgres as variable foo?

I just need to confirm this.
https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres#sample-configuration-5

Is this a purely ngx_postgres function or is this also available to nginx standalone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the nginx standard [regex named captures](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) feature:

E.g:

With this location:

```
location ~ /numbers/(?<num>\d+) {
 # I captured one ore more digits into the variable $num    
   ...
}
```

if the request is /numbers/100

The variable ***$num*** (with value 100) with be available in your location.